# Can I have my JMS topic notify the publisher when a new subscriber connects (using ActiveMQ)

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

The use case is that I want to send some configuration info to the subscribers as soon as they connect.

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
TopicConnectionFactory cf = (TopicConnectionFactory)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/xxx");
Topic topic = (Topic) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/xxx");           
TopicConnection conn = cf.createTopicConnection();
TopicSession session = conn.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);                    
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(topic);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you're looking for by consuming ActiveMQ's [advisory messages](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html), which will get published when (among other things) a consumer connects or disconnects.

Comment: Thank you but how would I set this up? I added my code above for setting up the MessageProducer

Comment: From your publisher process, you'd create a consumer on `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Topic.Foo`, and when it received a `ConsumerInfo` message type, you'd do whatever you wanted to do.  Using that mechanism, your publisher would find out as soon as a subscriber connected.